# Does linked server local login value support a windows AD group based sql login?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sql-server-2019

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#to-create-a-linked-server-to-another-instance-of-sql-server-using-sql-server-management-studio

I have a windows group configured as sql login.

While configuring linked server, under local login, I can see the windows group sql login listed in the dropdown.

The above link doesn't mention anything about windows group. Does linked server local login support windows group (with/without impersonation)? If not then why is that option showing up windows group in the dropdown?

This link says its not possible, but it's very old: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/linked-server-and-windows-group-local-login

I am looking for documentation mentioning about this.

[image]

Comment: SQL 2019 I do not see windows group in the drop-down.  I only see the principal types `SQL_LOGIN` and `WINDOWS_LOGIN`.

Comment: Thanks I think I might have confused since the names looked like group names. I take it that using groups is not possible then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, groups are not allowed; if you try you will get this error *xxxx\groupname is not a valid login or you do not have permission* even if the group is valid.
[image]
This is by design.

To use groups, you have to work with AD groups in the target server, set proper permission and use kerberos autentication. To do that you have to set connection made with "login's current security context".

[image: security]

With kerberos authentication you can authorize in target server a group and have your user use linked server with their windows logon on the remote server, based on group membership. But you have to setup kerberos constrained delegation. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-constrained-delegation-overview)

But you can do this only if the remote server is in the same or trusted domain and is using windows authentication.

Comment: You say the error is `xxxx\groupname is not a valid login or you do not have permission`, even though its a valid login?

Comment: I didn't get this point `To use groups, you have to use integrated security and domain groups, not local groups.`, can you explain.

Comment: I tried to reply to you editing the answer above

Comment: Does `Be made using this security context` (last option) work with groups?

Comment: When the AD group is a sql login on the server on which linked server is being setup, then why is group not allowed?

Comment: Be made using this security context works only with a single sql login, not a windows authentication

Comment: When the AD group is a sql login on the server on which linked server is being setup, then why is group not allowed? -> by design

Comment: `Be made using this security context works only with a single sql login, not a windows authentication` - yes you are right, what I mean is that: with this option, the target server is accessed using the sql login (of target sql server) configured (at the bottom of the screenshot), but the source user/group that is running the query using this linked server can be AD group or individual user, right?

Comment: right, the bad thing here is that all login converge to that individual remote login; so at target site, you can't distinguish or set different rights

Comment: Assuming there is NO KERBEROS (you have already confirmed that AD group login can be configured in the local login if kerberos is configured), I am wondering why is the design not allowing an AD group sql login (at source) to use a remote sql login when the same is supported by the above option (that is `Be made using this security context`).

Comment: remember that linked servers not always are related to sql server and/or windows integrated security so could happen that you are connecting with a thirt part DB.
usually the mapping is used in that cases. kerberos windows auth for sql server is the best option

Comment: I understand that windows user or group (in the Local Login dropdown) will not work with impersonation check-marked, if kerberos is not configured. Assuming kerberos is not configured, and impersonation checkmark is not checked, then all login types (that is - sql or windows or windows group based sql login) must be allowed to be provided in the Local Login. What is the harm in this?

Comment: I can only guess and my opinion is not relevant. The only fact is that it is not allowed.

Comment: But your screenshot says @useself = True, I assume this means impersonation is check-marked. Did you try with False?

Comment: @variable SQL logins don't use AD, only Windows Logins, and for that you need to use Kerberos aka Windows Authentication aka Integrated Security. Do not confuse the two

Comment: @charlieface- Firstly, I am referring to windows login. For some reason not clear to me, linked server doesn't support setting windows group based login in the local login dropdown. Secondly, why is Kerberos needed when the linked server is setup to use the remote user as sql login?